# ASP.NET Repeater with AsyncFileUpload inside UpdatePanel not updating

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am doing control panel where the user/admin can add a product to the database. Part of this consists of adding images to the product. To do this, I am using an UpdatePanel to only refresh the relevant page content, a Repeater with a table to display the currently uploaded images, and the AsyncFileUpload from the AJAX Control Toolkit to upload the files.

I am using the UploadedComplete event of the AsyncFileUpload to catch when the user has selected an image so I can save it to a temporary folder on the server, and create the DataClass objects (Image) that I both use for visualising the currently uploaded images, and for adding them to the database later.

My problem is that when I DataBind a list of the Images to the repeater and then call the Update method on the UpdatePanel that wraps it, the Repeater doesn't display.

I placed a breakpoint at the start of the UploadedComplete event confirmed that the List of Images actually gets DataBound to the Repeater - it just doesn't show up.

Relevant part of AdminProduct.aspx:

```
<div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <h2 class="mb-0">Billeder</h2>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel_Add_Images" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                        <Triggers>
                                        </Triggers>
                                        <ContentTemplate>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Tilføj billede</label>
                                                <div class="custom-file">
                                                    <ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload_Add_AddImage" runat="server" CssClass="custom-file-input" OnUploadedComplete="AsyncFileUpload_Add_AddImage_UploadedComplete" />
                                                    <label class="custom-file-label">Vælg fil...</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel_Add_UploadImageList" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                                <ContentTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater_Add_ImageList" runat="server">
                                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                                            <table class="table table-responsive-md">
                                                                <tbody>
                                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <%# Eval("ImageOriginalFileName") %>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton_Add_RemoveImage" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt ml-0"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                        </FooterTemplate>
                                                    </asp:Repeater>
                                                </ContentTemplate>
                                            </asp:UpdatePanel>

                                        </ContentTemplate>
                                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

AsyncFileUpload UploadedComplete event:

```
protected void AsyncFileUpload_Add_AddImage_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {

        List<Image> addImageList;

        if (Session["ImageList"] != null)
        {
            addImageList = (List<Image>)Session["ImageList"];
        }
        else
        {
            addImageList = new List<Image>();
        }

        string imageGUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        string imageName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(AsyncFileUpload_Add_AddImage.FileName);
        AsyncFileUpload_Add_AddImage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/Resources/Temp/" + imageGUID + ".jpg"));

        Image newImage = new Image();
        newImage.ImagePath = imageGUID;
        newImage.ImageOriginalFileName = imageName;

        addImageList.Add(newImage);
        Session["ImageList"] = addImageList;

        Repeater_Add_ImageList.DataSource = addImageList;
        Repeater_Add_ImageList.DataBind();

        UpdatePanel_Add_UploadImageList.Update();

    }
```

The "Image" is an object from my database, represented by LINQ to SQL.

Comment: Your XML is far from being _well-formed_. It needs some serious fixing.

Comment: @zx485 Can you elaborate? What's wrong with it?

Comment: I put your XML in an XSLT processor and tried to copy it identically. It failed big times. Namespace errors and some opening tags did not match the closing tags. Serious errors, too many for editing your question. Check it out by yourself.

Comment: If you ask what I did: I tried to put your XML though an XSLT _identity template_. This failed.

Comment: @zx485 I don't see any opening tags that are missing closing tags. What do you mean by namespace errors?

Comment: Did you even try to validate the XML? For example, `<HeaderTemplate>` is not closed before `<table class="table table-responsive-md">` and `<tbody>` are closed. **This is not well-formed.**

Comment: That's completely on purpose. It's a Repeater template. I'm not supposed to close the table, etc. inside the HeaderTemplate, because then the delivered HTML will be wrong. This is ASPX.

Once it has been processed by the server, the resulting HTML will be correct.

Comment: If that is intentional, I apologize. But I also cannot help you in this regard. Good luck for your future endeavors.